# Windows 10 notifications

Tags: windows, push-notification, windows-10, pushsharp

Is it possible to send (push) notifications to windows 10 pc, without having any application installed there?

We have Windows 10 as standard operating system, and we would like to send notifications to the staff.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 and up uses the WNS web service for push notification. Unfortunately, the API is severely locked down. For starter, it is not available to desktop app, so you need to make a metro/modern/universal app.

According to MSDN
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview 
your pc runs the wns background service, which is a program that maintains a https connection to wns.windows.com all the time.

The developer set up his app account with MS, and gets a unique app id. Then he makes the app, embedding his app id inside. The app, when installed by the user, will tell WNS.windows.com it wants to subscribe to all messages tagged with that appid.

To push a message to the pc, the developer sends a message to wns.windows.com, specifying the appid. Wns.windows.com will forward the message to the user pc. Locally, WNS background service receives the message, then decides which app to pass that message to. It will launch that app if required.

So back to your question. No it is not possible to do it without installing an app. I imagine you can hook onto the wns background service and intercept the message, but the inner works of wns is totally undocumented and the message is secured by ssl anyway.

A easier alternative I can think of is having the users open a website and poll for messages.

Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Your app requests a push notification channel from the Universal Windows Platform.

Windows asks WNS to create a notification channel. This channel is returned to the calling device in the form of a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).

The notification channel URI is returned by Windows to your app.

Your app sends the URI to your own cloud service. You then store the URI on your own cloud service so that you can access the URI when you send notifications. The URI is an interface between your own app and your own service; it's your responsibility to implement this interface with safe and secure web standards.

When your cloud service has an update to send, it notifies WNS using the channel URI. This is done by issuing an HTTP POST request, including the notification payload, over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL). This step requires authentication.

WNS receives the request and routes the notification to the appropriate device.